# github's gh-pages doesn't updated

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a github page for my project. The project name is goblock.

However, when I visit https://gofrendiasgard.github.io/goblock and view source of index.html, I find it differ from https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/goblock/blob/gh-pages/index.html

The most noticeable different is the existence of these elements:

`<div id="__lesson" class="col-md-7"></div>

            <div id="__lessonResult" class="col-md-5"></div>`

on line 37.

Firstly, I think it is just a caching problem, but after I clean up my browser history, I still get the same result.

I even try to use different computer with no luck.

Does anybody ever experience such a problem?

How to enforce update to my gh-pages?

Comment: Someone from github suggest me to do some changes and push to gh-pages again. Seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

Push your code to the branch that you have configured in the repository settings as your github pages branch.

In your case, and for the default case for a github pages "project page" the branch that you should commit your site code to is `gh-pages`.